# Jquery mobile - radio button widget for dynamic html contents created via ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, radio-button, refresh

I am new to jQuery mobiles. The radio button widget is properly rendering if I hard code that in a HTML file but the widget is not loading for the same HTML contents which I dynamically created from JavaScript via Ajax.

when i try `checkboxradio( "refresh" )`, I am getting an error like

> "cannot call methods on checkboxradio prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'"

Any suggestion on how should I refresh the dynamic contents to get the JQM widgets?

Answer (score 2):

Enhance the markup of Checkbox and Radio buttons dynamically using both `.checkboxradio()` and `.trigger('create')`.

```
$('input[type=radio]').checkboxradio().trigger('create');
```